# Is drawing partial bodies for fashion illustrations allowed?

Tags: drawing, fashion-design

For my fashion course I must draw animate beings such as the human figure to design garments and make my collections etc.  However, I know that I am not allowed to draw them so would I be able to draw like the body and stuff but not the face?

I have recently changed the way I draw like rather than drawing the figure for my designs I just outline the parts I need to like the hands and head and hair, but don't draw the facial features and just design my garments.  Does Islam say that this is allowed?

Because I will be getting a career in fashion design so as a designer I will be expected to design and draw garments before I actually make them.